# How to float a variable declared by an equation to two decimal places in java

Tags: java, decimal

How to I make the answer display in two decimal places?

```
runningCalories  = 0.0175 * RUNNING_METS * weight * TIME_RUNNING;
System.out.println(name + " burned an estimated " + runningCalories + " calories running.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
System.out.printf("%s burned an estimated %.2f calories running.", name, runningCalories);
```